# Analysis Service connection issue

Tags: sql-server, ssas

I'm new to SQL Server.

I downloaded

adventure-works-multidimensional-model-full-database-backup.zip

adventure-works-tabular-model-1200-full-database-backup.zip
from GitHub

I would like to restore this in SQL Management Studio Analysis Services, but to do this, I need to create an instance

According to Microsoft, I installed
1)MS SQL Server Management Studio 2)MS SQL Server Data Tools
How do I create Analysis Service Instance to log into so I can restore adventure-works-tabular-model-1200-full-database-backup > Adventure Works Internet Sales Tabular Sample Database > Adventure Works Internet Sales Database.abf

I searched and found this: Restore Instance of Analysis Service I downloaded the SQL Server Developer Edition, but I'm still not able to connect, the server name field is not auto-populating, I tried with localhost\SQLEXPRESS, but it's not working (and it works if I select "DB engine" from the drop-down list). The error says: "A connection cannot be made to redirector. Ensure that 'SQL Browser' service is running. (Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient). Can't establish a connection to 127.0.0.1:2832(System)".

I checked, and the SQL Browser is running properly, set on "local system".

Might it be a firewall issue?

I can't upload any image, sorry.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I create Analysis Service Instance to log into so

You have to install it.  You can download [Developer Edition](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads), and run the installer to add an Analysis Services instance in Tabular mode.